# Maven is downloading one jar from artifactory whereas two jars avilable with same groupid,artifactid and version in different repo

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I have two jars in artifactory having same groupid,artifact id and version but they are having little difference in code.One jar file is in libs-release-repo and other one is in snapshot repository of artifactory. My question is my pom file is downloading the dependency but it is downloading the one which is in release repository why it is not downloading the one which is in snapshot repository.All repositories are defined in setting.xml file.Can someone let me know why pom.xml is downloading the one which is in release repository?

Comment: *I have two jars in artifactory having same groupid,artifact id and version but they are having little difference in code.* <-- fix this. Honestly, don't say anything else and fix this NOW. This is very, _very_ bad. This is something that should never happen and it goes against the very definition of the Maven coordinates, which are supposed to be _unique_. This is the root cause of all your problems. You cannot solve your others problems. Don't even try, you cannot do it. Even if by a pure stroke of luck it "works", it would be utterly fragile and simply wrong.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.Thanks

Comment: Awesome :) Maybe the simplest solution is to have a different version or a classifier added. What you want is just to have a different set of Maven coordinates.

Comment: Yes I suggested to go with different version.

Comment: If you are having the same version in release repo and in snapshot repo than there is going something very bad wrong, a snapshot repo will never contain release artifacts. Releases in Maven having versions like `1.0.0` whereas snapshots having versions like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`...so there should never be a conflict but if yaou cleanup your SNAPSHOT repo...